# Is it possible to sort the results of a select by relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is it possible to sort the results of a select by relationships?

I have a one to many relationship. A product has multiple items. And each item has a price. I need to fetch the products, however the ordering of the products must be for the price of the items

Let me give you an example:

```
Product::with(['items'])->whereHas('items', function ($query) {

    $query->orderBy('price', 'desc')

})->get();
```

It would be something like that. But I need to sorting the products per prices that are inside the items.

if my database has the following:

```
product 1
  item $ 1.2
  item $ 2.0

product 2
  item $ 3.0
  item $ 0.5

product 3
  item 1.0
```

I need a return:

```
product 2
  item $ 3.0
  item $ 0.5

product 3
  item 1.0

product 1
  item $ 1.2
  item $ 2.0
```

because it was considered the lowest item of each product. How could I do this query using enloquent?

Comment: Please check my answer if working :)

Comment: your return confuses me. It is neither in `prices->high-to-low` nor `prices->low-to-high`

Answer (score 0):

can you try this on your query.

```
Product::withCount(['items as ItemTotalAmount' => function($q){
        $q->select(DB::raw("SUM(price)"));
}])
->with('items')
->orderBy('ItemTotalAmount', 'ASC')->get();
```

In this query, it sum first the Items Price and put the Total in the Alias `ItemTotalAmount`

Then I used `orderBy` in the `ItemTotalAmount` to sort the products that has more total of items price.

Answer (score 0):

`whereHas` is typically used to query relationship existence with additional `where()` conditions. From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships):

> If you need even more power, you may use the whereHas and orWhereHas
>   methods to put "where" conditions on your has queries. These methods
>   allow you to add customized constraints to a relationship constraint.

In your particular case, you just want to order the eager-loaded relations. As such, the following should do the trick instead.

```
$product = Product::with(['items' => function($query) {
        $query->orderBy('price', 'asc');
    }])
    ->get();
```